# Include js files for specific views

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to include a custom js file in a view. I have tried this in the view:

```
 <% content_for :head do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.0.6/kinetic.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "diagramtool" %>
 <% end %>

<div id="container"></div>
<div id="flash"></div>
```

the `diagramtool.js` is in `app/assets/javascript`
And I have remove this lines from `application.js`because I do not want to load the js file diagramtool in other views.

```
//= require kinetic
//= require diagramtool
//= require_tree .
```

But I'm getting this error:

[image]

How should I do this? In witch directory should I put the js file that I just want to load in some specific views?

Comment: All your JS files should be in `assets/javascripts` IIRC, so Rails can find them.

Answer (score 0):

Load the main JavaScript in application.js every time. Create a dasgboard.js file. Don't load them in the application.html.erb layout. Load them dynamically when you need them:

application.html.erb:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= yield :javascript_includes %>
```

top of your view.html.erb:

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "dasgboard.js" %>
<% end %>
```